# How to add a year to an Instant in NodaTime?

Tags: c#, nodatime

From [NodaTime's documentation](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/arithmetic) I understand why there is no AddYear on a ZonedDateTime or an Instant. I need some way to get to 'this time next year' however (all the times I need are stored/used in UTC). So far, what I've come up with is this:

```
var start = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant().InUtc();
var nextyear = start.Date.PlusYears(1).At(start.TimeOfDay).InUtc().ToInstant();
```

Is that the right way to do this? Which of all the reasons for not having an AddYear on ZonedDateTime might I run into problems with here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're *only* dealing with UTC, and you're *only* using the ISO (Gregorian) calendar, then what you've got should be okay, although it can be simplified to:

```cs
var nextYear = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant()
   .InUtc()
   .LocalDateTime
   .PlusYears(1)
   .InUtc()
   .ToInstant();
```

The reason it's okay to do this for UTC is that UTC doesn't have any transitions - you don't need to worry about "one year from this local date/time" being either ambiguous or skipped.

It's just worth being aware of *exactly* what you're doing - that you're adding a year to "the current Gregorian date/time in UTC", not adding a year to "the current instant in time", because an instant doesn't have a concept of "a year".